# Replace a 36" door with a Five ft slider on a two story load bearing out side wall

Tags: doors, framing

What should the header size be? I was thinking two 2x12.
One king and two jack studs on each side?
Do I need to build a temp support while installing the new header?

Comment: Is the door going to be on the first or second story? 2-2x12's should be good for a header of 5' even on the first story.

Comment: First floor and thanks for the info it's a big help

Answer (score 1):

The 2x12's are good. 2x10's are calculated to be enough.  Double jack studs are good.  And definitely provide temporary support. This information is available on Table # `R502.5(2)` P.

Comment: Paul, you might add the title of the document that the table came from e.g. International Building Code, Table R502.5(2)